# Multiple date adds - is a loop possible?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am pretty new to SQL and I am trying to create a statement that will add a week to a date and list said date under a week number.

The output is working fine:

```
fin_year | MondayWeek1Date |     WK1    |     WK2    | 
2016     | 2015-07-27      | 2015-07-27 | 2015-08-03 |
```

Code:

```
SELECT  fin_year, MondayWeek1Date,
             DATEADD(WK,0,MondayWeek1Date) AS WK1,
             DATEADD(WK,1,MondayWeek1Date) AS WK2,
             DATEADD(WK,2,MondayWeek1Date) AS WK3,
             DATEADD(WK,3,MondayWeek1Date) AS WK4,
             DATEADD(WK,4,MondayWeek1Date) AS WK5,
             DATEADD(WK,5,MondayWeek1Date) AS WK6,
             DATEADD(WK,6,MondayWeek1Date) AS WK7,
             DATEADD(WK,7,MondayWeek1Date) AS WK8
    FROM         server.financeYearStartDate
    WHERE     (fin_year = @fin_period)
```

But is there a way for me to loop the DATEADDs to a certain point so I don't have to have 52/53 dateadd lines?

Thanks!

Neil

Comment: Why not do this in whatever program you need the info instead?

Comment: I would rather join this as a dataset rather than let SSRS do the calculation

Comment: I think this is sql server, not mysql?

Answer (score 0):

If this is SQL Server as I suppose, you can add the weeks with a recursive cte and then pivot into columns. Example:

```
-- temp table to use in the example
    create table #financeYearStartDate
    (fin_year integer, MondayWeek1Date date)
    insert into #financeYearStartDate
    Values
    (2016,'2016-01-04'),
    (2017,'2017-01-02')

-- 

;with cte
as 
(select fin_year, cast('MondayWeek1Date' as varchar(15)) as weeknumber, MondayWeek1Date weekdate, 0 wn from #financeYearStartDate
union all
select fin_year, 'W' + cast(wn+1 as varchar(14)) weeknumber, DATEADD(WK,1,weekdate), wn+1 wn from cte where wn<53
)

SELECT fin_year, 
[MondayWeek1Date], 
[W1], [W2], [W3], [W4], [W5], [W6], [W7], [W8], [W9], [W10],
[W11], [W12], [W13], [W14], [W15], [W16], [W17], [W18], [W19], [W20], 
[W21], [W22], [W23], [W24], [W25], [W26], [W27], [W28], [W29], [W30], 
[W31], [W32], [W33], [W34], [W35], [W36], [W37], [W38], [W39], [W40], 
[W41], [W42], [W43], [W44], [W45], [W46], [W47], [W48], [W49], [W50], 
[W51], [W52]
FROM
(SELECT fin_year, weeknumber, weekdate 
    FROM cte) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
Max(weekdate)
FOR weeknumber IN ([MondayWeek1Date], 
[W1], [W2], [W3], [W4], [W5], [W6], [W7], [W8], [W9], [W10],
[W11], [W12], [W13], [W14], [W15], [W16], [W17], [W18], [W19], [W20], 
[W21], [W22], [W23], [W24], [W25], [W26], [W27], [W28], [W29], [W30], 
[W31], [W32], [W33], [W34], [W35], [W36], [W37], [W38], [W39], [W40], 
[W41], [W42], [W43], [W44], [W45], [W46], [W47], [W48], [W49], [W50], 
[W51], [W52])
) AS PivotTable
```

Comment: Looks like what I need, thanks for this Jayvee. Will give it a shot!

Comment: i've removed the @i as it wasn't necessary; directly harcoding wn=0 in the anchor is enough

Comment: also amended year 2017 to start on 2017-01-02 for the sake of the example